# create a process and redirect its input/output and dont inherit socket handles

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Is it possible to create a process and redirect its input and output but set the child not to inherit socket handles ? ( maybe pinvoke with CreateProcess somehow )
If I use UseShellExecute = true the child doesn't inherit the socket but I cant redirect output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425) takes a [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331) as one of its parameters. Three of the fields in this struct are the in, out and error handles.

Don't forget to set the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag.

Edit: So you have to set the `bInheritHandles` parameter. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724466) for more information about inherited handles.

Comment: wont this cause the child process to inherit the socket handles also ?

Comment: If you set the `bInheritHandles` parameter on the `CreateProcess` to false, no handles will be inherited. MSDN does not say that you have to inherit handles for this this to work.

Comment: @jacob Wait -- that's not true. You have to set the `bInheritHandles`. But according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724466) only handles with specific security attributes will be inherited.

Comment: @jacob No, sorry, but should be straight forward to write out.