# C# App is unable to close properly after it launches another app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have very strange behavior that I cannot understand. 
Scenario: I've written simple clinet-server app (with C# 4.5, using WCF). 
Server's task is (among other things) - is to launch various programs on clients request. 
Scenario for example:

1. I start server.exe  on computer A, (it starts to listen to defined port).
2. I lunch client.exe on computer B, and request server to open
   Notepad.exe
3. Notepad.exe opens fine on pc A.
4. I close server.exe on pc A (but leave notepad open), I verify that
   server.exe process is not running in task manager.
5. I try to reopen server.exe -> I get an exception that another
   program is already listening on given port - this exception also
   occurs, when I try to open 2nd server.exe  instance, w/o closing
   first.

**?? Can anyone explain this behavior?**

6. When I first close the notepad.exe, and then close server.exe on pc
   A - and only then try to reopen server.exe - it opens w/o any issue.

Comment: How are you launching notepad.exe? Try setting ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; When creating child processes, if UseShellExecute is set to false, then the child process will inherit open socket handles from the parent process.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm using this to launch the app:   `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            p.Start(); `

Comment: I tried changing to true, but I get this error: `InvalidOperationException: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)`

Comment: You could trying calling the native CreateProcess Win32API function using pinvoke. The function has a parameter named bInheritHandles which you can set to false. However you will need to also use the native APIs in order to redirect your streams. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638901/create-a-process-and-redirect-its-input-output-and-dont-inherit-socket-handles